# My LeanFT Trial License which has the duration of 60 days expires immediately after 1 day of the installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, leanft

I installed the Visual Studio 217.
I downloaded and installed the LeanFT after making the credentials at their respective website. On website, it is displaying the remaining days as 60.
I launched the Visual Studio and started working on LeanFT.
I finished the POc and shutdown everything.
Next day, when i relaunched visual studio. it starts giving me the message "The LeanFT Runtime engine requires a valid functional testing licence". and all menu items for LeanFt got disabled. when i executed the code, it is also giving the same error.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could it be that the system's clock was tampered with? Many license mechanisms detect this and then don't trust the system time.

Comment: It's a new VM and clock has not been tempered.